# how to write UTF8 data to xml file using RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, utf-8, randomaccessfile

When trying to write some UTF8 data to a file, I end up with some garbage in the file. The code is as follows

```
public static boolean saveToFile(StringBuffer buffer,
                                   String fileName,
                                   ArrayList exceptionList,
                                   String className)
  {
    log.debug("In saveToFile for file [" + fileName + "]");

                RandomAccessFile raf = null;
                File file = new File(fileName);
                File backupFile = new File(fileName+"_bck");

                try
                {
                    if (file.exists())
                    {
                            if (backupFile.exists())
                            {
                            backupFile.delete();
                            }
                            file.renameTo(backupFile);
                    }
                    raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
                    raf.writeBytes(buffer.toString());
                    raf.close();
```

The output of buffer.toString() is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivr>
<version>1.1</version>
<templateName>αβγδεζη
```

The data in the file however is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ivr>
<version>1.1</version>
<templateName>▒▒▒▒▒▒▒</templateName>
```

How can I make sure that data i nthe file itself is UTF8

Comment: Have you tried writeUTF rather than writeBytes?

Comment: I have modified the post to include the inclusion of buffer etc. Basically buffer is passed in to  the function. I have already printed the buffer.toString() output in the post above. If I didnt clarify your question then please let me know

Comment: I havent tried writeUTF as yet, though it is on my todo list. The concern I have regarding writeUTF is that (I read somewhere) writeUTF  first writes the number of characters to file and then the characters. Plus the other concern I have is whether writeUTF  is UTF8 or UTF16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not surpised you get garbage:

```
 raf.writeBytes(buffer.toString())
```

The documentation for [`RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeBytes%28java.lang.String%29) says (emphasis added):

> Writes the string to the file as a sequence of bytes. Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, *by discarding its high eight bits*.

In a few circumstances, that operation will result in a correctly encoded file. But in most it won't. That `writeBytes()` method is a foolish design by the Java developers. You need to correctly encode your text as bytes in UTF-8, and then write those bytes.

Do you *really* need to operate on the file as a random access file. If not, just manipulate it with a `Writer` wrapping an `OutputStream`.

You could use [`Charset.encode(CharBuffer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#encode%28java.nio.CharBuffer%29) to produce a `ByteBuffer` holding the encoded bytes, then write those bytes to the file:

```
 raf.write(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(buffer).array());
```

Comment: Yes while discussing offline in the office, even we were coming to the same conclusion that the code needs to be redone to start using something like OutputStream etc.

Comment: `StandardCharsets.UTF_8.encode(buffer).array()` seemed when I tried it to produce a Bytes stream of the same length as twice the number of characters in the original, even if the UTF-8 representation didn't contain that many characters, with the rest being nulls. Rather use `buffer.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc for RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeBytes(java.lang.String)) states that for `writeBytes()`

> Writes the string to the file as a sequence of bytes. Each character
>   in the string is written out, in sequence, **by discarding its high
>   eight bits**. The write starts at the current position of the file
>   pointer.

Assuming that discarding parts of your String *isn't* what you want, you should be using [writeUtf()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)):

> Writes a string to the file using modified UTF-8 encoding in a
>   machine-independent manner.

Comment: I will try writeUTF() though just for experiment as I am now more inclined to use OutputStream etc

Answer (score 0):

```
String txt = buffer.toString();
raf.write(txt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation what this code does, and how it answers the question? Answers with a little explanation are usually more helpful than just code.