# CSV not showing correct data

Tags: java, csv

```java
    package aplikacja;
    import java.io.*;

    public class Plik {
        double wymiary[] =  {10, 23, 4};

        public void zapisz_dane() throws IOException{
           RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("pomiary.csv", "rw");
            for(int i =0; i<wymiary.length; i++){
                raf.writeDouble(wymiary[i]);
            }
            raf.close();
        }

    }
```

And this:

```java
    package aplikacja;
    import java.io.*;
    import aplikacja.*;

    public class Main {
        public static void main (String []args) throws IOException {
            Plik plik = new Plik();
            plik.zapisz_dane();
        }
    }
```

When I open CSV files I have chars insides CSV file:

```
@$@7@
```

But I would like to have 10, 23 and 4.
How to fix it?

It is working for `String` but not for `double` or `int`. Do you know why?

Comment: Check out the javadoc on RandomAccessFile.writeDouble(double).  You are writing out a byte representation of the double values, not String representation.  You may want to use a PrintWriter to write to your underlying File.  And don't forget to write the commas - its only comma-separated if you separate things with commas!

Answer (score 0):

A solution using [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html):

```java
package aplikacja;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class Plik {

  double[] wymiary = { 10, 23, 4 };

  public void zapiszDane() throws IOException {

    File file = new File("pomiary.csv");

    try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file)) {
      for (int i = 0; i < wymiary.length; i++) {
        pw.println(wymiary[i]);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

**pomiary.csv result:**

```
10.0
23.0
4.0
```

---

***Note:*** in general there is no way to determine the decimal precision of a `double` value. If you want decimal precision in Java, you could use `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the charset (usually UTF-8). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24933143) for how to do it. There are more information on that stack overflow thread.